# There is issue in Gradle File(error message in below)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Error Message-

> Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments
>   [build_8yvoh28709tkfmgonv9e1pntf$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6@7e2c902d] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null,
>   minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=19, mCodename='null'},
>   targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=25, mCodename='null'},
>   renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=1, versionName=1.0,
>   applicationId=com.vpaliy.loginconcept, testApplicationId=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunner=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner,
>   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null,
>   testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
>   mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
>   mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={},
>   mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

Here it is build.gradle(module.app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vpaliy.loginconcept"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'                                                                                                                                 

    compile'net.yslibrary
      .keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I see no "jackOptions" in https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.html

Comment: **The Jack toolchain is deprecated.** Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Android studio 3.1, JackOptions have been deprecated. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#disable_jack):

> If your project depends on Jack, you should migrate to using Java 8 support built into Android Studio’s default toolchain.
>
> To disable Jack and switch to the default toolchain, **simply remove the
>   jackOptions block from your module’s build.gradle**

You can refer to the announcement [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the pointed steps-
1.// Remove this block.

```
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
```

2.//add this block in gradle.properties file.

```
     android.enableDesugar=true
```

Comment: you don't have to put `android.enableDesugar=true` since its enabled by default. Remember to mark the answer as accepted (whichever has helped you) so that other's can benefit too.